# Material design 3 how to disable elevation overlay?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-dark-theme, material-design-3

Android material 3 has introduced elevation overlays(tonal color overlays). Which causes background color change for MaterialCard views if `android:elevation` is provided or increased and impacts the original background color.

1. How to style material 3 elevation overlays?
2. How to disable material 3 elevation overlays to avoid background color change for card views if elevation is provided to the view.

Documentation doesn't provide much information related to styling or disabling elevation overlays.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#elevation
https://m3.material.io/styles/elevation/applying-elevation

Comment: "I came across elevation overlay several times" -- can you edit your question and provide links to the places that are using this term? Are you referring to https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/?

Comment: detailed here https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#elevation-in-material-design

Comment: Thanks for your comment CommonsWare. I edited it

Comment: Thank you Yunus for the link, but I can't see a lot of use of it;(. I want to know how it is used(in what circumstances)

Comment: It's a very annoying and stupid feature.  Material shouldn't be deciding what color a background is.  Most of us in the professional field have design requirements.

Answer (score 16):

As you can find in the [doc](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/):

> in a **dark theme** the elevation overlays are semi-transparent white
>   (`colorOnSurface`) overlays that are conceptually placed on top of the
>   surface color.

It is **managed by the library**.
Just an example with a `MaterialCardView` with `app:cardElevation="4dp"` and `app:cardElevation="8dp"`.

Light mode:

[image]

Dark mode:

[image]

The overlay is based on the `colorOnSurface` defined in the app theme.
You can change this color adding in the app theme:

```
<item name="elevationOverlayColor">@color/...</item>
```

[image]

You can also disable this behavior using in the app theme:

```
<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
```

Many components in the Material Components Library support elevation overlays in dark theme but you can also apply it in your custom view using using the **`MaterialShapeDrawable`**.

For example you can use a `LinearLayout`:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout1= findViewById(R.id....);
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawableLL1 = 
MaterialShapeDrawable.createWithElevationOverlay(this, 4.0f );
ViewCompat.setBackground(linearLayout1,shapeDrawableLL1);

LinearLayout linearLayout2= findViewById(R.id....);
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawableLL2 = 
MaterialShapeDrawable.createWithElevationOverlay(this, 16.0f );
ViewCompat.setBackground(linearLayout2,shapeDrawableLL2);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have understood much better now

Comment: Thanks. I thought I can set `"elevationOverlayEnabled"=false` on an individual `view`. I see now it has to be set in the `theme`.